# How to redirect www to non-www static website on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

I've spent a few hours to solve redirection from www to non-www version of static site hosted on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two lamda@edge with cloudfront.

**First lambda@edge - CloudFront Event is Viewer request**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request
  request.headers['x-forwarded-host'] = [
    { key: 'X-Forwarded-Host', value: request.headers.host[0].value }
  ]
  return callback(null, request)
}
```

**Second lambda@edge - CloudFront Event is Origin request**

```
exports.handler = function handler(event, context, callback) {
  const { request } = event.Records[0].cf;
  const { uri } = request;
  const { suffix, appendToDirs, removeTrailingSlash } = config;
  const requestHost = request.headers['x-forwarded-host'][0].value;
  
if (requestHost.startsWith("www.")) {
    const domain_without_www = requestHost.replace("www.","");
    var location = "https://" + domain_without_www + request.uri;
    
    var responseWithRedirect = {
      status: '301',
      statusDescription: `Redirecting to apex domain`,
      headers: {
        location: [{
          key: 'Location',
          value: location
        }]
      }
    };
    callback(null, responseWithRedirect);
    return;

  }
  // or return request unchanged
  callback(null, request);
}
```

The last step is add "x-forwarded-host" header to whitelist headers in you distribution - behavior section.

I've found this solution in AWS forum, but it was difficult to find it. I believe this will help you.